# Device compatible CSS - @media

Tags: html, css, web, media, device-compatibility

I am currently using 
@media only screen and (max-width:1000px) {}
for device compatible css for my website which worked on phones after upload but not on a small monitor pc (around 1200px width). It supposedly was working on my home pc when I adjusted the width of the browser. Is the syntax line correct?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You must share your code with css to find the solution

Comment: You can find the common media queries for devices over here - [Refer](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line was missing from the head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Along with that was browser cache to  add to the misery of my CSS life.

Answer (score 0):

Your media query might be overlapping. Try this below one

```
@media screen (min-width: 800px) {
         //your style here !
    }

@media screen (min-width: 1200px) {
         //your style here !
    }
```

Comment: I tried, but certain elements of the mobile versions of lesser width were not able to override the primary design.